# Errors computing PSD inside parfor loops but not for loops

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compute a series of spectra in parallel using `parfor`, but my `parfor` loops crash.

I'm fairly confident that the crash isn't due to failure to pre-allocate variables but rather that matlab is computing the spectrum in a different way:

Here is an simple script that demonstrates the problem (On Ubuntu & R2012b):

```
% allocate the data and objects
mtm = spectrum.mtm;
data = rand(3000,1);
Fs = 500;

fprintf('Entering for loop\n');
for i = 1:5
    h = psd(mtm, data, 'Fs', Fs);
end

fprintf('Entering parfor loop\n');
parfor i = 1:10
    h = psd(mtm, data, 'Fs', Fs);
end
```

The `for` loop executes correctly, however, the `parfor` errors out. Here is the output:

> Entering for loop
>
> Entering parfor loop
>
> Warning: PSD has been replaced
>     by SPECTRUM objects. PSD still works but may be removed in the future.
>     Use SPECTRUM (or its functional form PWELCH) instead.
>
> > In psd at 33   In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general at 885   In
> >     remoteParallelFunction at 30  Error using parallel_function (line 589)
>
> Requires vector (either row or column) input.
>
> Error stack: psd.m at 37

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a better way to parallelize the spectral computations?

Comment: Does the code work properly if you replace parfor with for? If so I guess that in the parallel universe the future has come now

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, Yes, that is what the included code demonstrates

Comment: Can you just switch to `spectrum` as the error message suggests?

Comment: @shoelzer, the odd thing is that I'm syntax associated with the NEW spectrum objects, yet I'm getting warnings as if I'm using the OLD spectrum syntax. Notice how I don't get the warning on the first call to `psd`

Comment: There is a race condition in your for loop: the result of each iteration is stored in the variable `h`. This creates a race condition in parallel, where each parallel task tries to write into `h` at the same time. Try changing `h=psd(...)` to `h(i)=psd(...)`, so that the result of each iteration is stored in a separate location. However, I suspect that you actually want to parallelize the computations inside the `psd` function, is this the case?

Comment: @bcumming, this isn't a race condition. The parallel computing toolbox doesn't work the way you've described it. Variables declared inside a `parfor` loop, only exist within that iteration and are not preserved upon termination of the loop.  Each worker, literally, operates on a different output variable `h`.

Comment: @slayton: you are right, `h` has got local scope inside the loop. But from your code example, it isn't clear why you have the for loop in the first place. The input values, `mtm`, `data` and `FS` are the same each time `psd()` is called. In your actual application do you use different inputs at each iteration?

Comment: @bcumming, the code I posted isn't code I actually use, rather its a simple example that demonstrated the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Mathworks support the problem is solved by moving the creation of the `spectrum.mtm` object inside the `parfor` loop.

#### This works

```
fprintf('Entering parfor loop\n');
parfor i = 1:10
    mtm = spectrum.mtm;
    h = psd(mtm, data, 'Fs', Fs);
end
```

#### This does't

```
mtm = spectrum.mtm;

fprintf('Entering parfor loop\n');
parfor i = 1:10
    h = psd(mtm, data, 'Fs', Fs);
end
```

The underlying problem is that `spectrum.mtm` is a simulink object, not a matlab object and simulink objects cannot be used in `parfor` loops.